# Find set of number corresponding to a number

Tags: ruby

From a number, I want to generate the different groups of numbers where the sum corresponds to this number.

Example:

```
generate_groups([], 1) would be equal to [ [1] ]
generate_groups([], 2) would be equal to [ [1,1] , [2] ]
generate_groups([], 3) would be equal to [ [1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3] ]
```

I already wrote the solution in iterative code but there's a better answer in recursive.

So, I wrote the following code:

```
def generate_groups(combo = [], rest)
  return combo.flatten if rest <= 0

  result = []
  (1..rest).each do |number|
    combo << number
    tmp_res = generate_groups(combo, rest-number)
    result << tmp_res
    combo.pop
  end
  return result
end
```

But it's not good because it generates array in array.
For example, `generate_groups([], 3)` is:

```
[ [ [ [1, 1, 1] ], [1, 2] ] , [ [2, 1] ] , [3] ]
```

What's wrong in my algorithm?

Comment: unrelated to your algorithm, but perhaps a quick ruby tip: if you reverse the arguments for generate_groups, then you can have the second one actually be optional (`generate_groups(rest, combo=[])`) to be called like `generate_groups(1) or generate_groups(1, [])`

Comment: @TMP: This works like it is too (since Ruby 2, IIRC).

Comment: @undur_gongor oh okay, that's cool I didn't know that. It just looked odd to me for you to be specifying the empty array in your example though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution can be fixed like this:

```
def generate_groups(combo = [], rest)
  return [combo.dup] if rest <= 0  # no need for flattening 

  result = []
  (1..rest).each do |number|
    combo << number
    tmp_res = generate_groups(combo, rest-number)
    result += tmp_res # concat the solutions instead of nesting them.
    combo.pop
  end
  return result
end
```

The `dup` is necessary because otherwise the fixed result will later be changed by changing `combo`. Your `flatten` also created a copy of the array.

However, passing the internal state (`combo`) through the recursion looks ... strange. It is not needed. My proposal

```
def generate_groups(rest)
  return [[]] if rest <= 0

  (1..rest).inject([]) do | a, number |
    a + generate_groups(rest - number).map { | g | g << number }
  end
end
```

With the `inject`, I concatenate the intermediate result arrays.